# how to convert img to Image component in Nextjs13?

Tags: css, next.js13

I am having some trouble converting my img tag that has some preset styling to the Image component in nextjs13. the trouble is I have some styling on the width, so I can't use fill={true} as it requires width=100%. as such I am not sure what to set the width and height too. Here is my tag:

```
<img
    src={ImgSrc}
    alt={`An image of the ${title} project.`}
    style={{
        width: hovered ? "90%" : "85%",
        rotate: hovered ? "2deg" : "0deg",
    }}
/>
```

All the images are png/jpg 642x408. When I set the height and width to those numbers the width styling doesnt get applied.

I am using TypeScript btw

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `next/images` package to your code (in same file with your `Image` component):

```
import Image from 'next/image'
```

To do this, you have to install the associated npm package using following command:

```
npm install next/image
```

Now, your code will be like following:

```
<Image
    src={ImgSrc}
    alt={`An image of the ${title} project.`}
    width={hovered ? "90%" : "85%"}
    height={hovered ? "auto" : "auto"} 
    style={{ transform: hovered ? "rotate(2deg)" : "rotate(0deg)" }}
/>
```

Note: The Image Component requires the following properties: `src`, `width`, `height`, and `alt`.
**Reference: [NextJS Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image)**

Comment: Will that not return a type error? Width and Height only accept int